# Extract files with special characters in filenames from a rar archive using the shell

Tags: ubuntu, archiving, rar

We are receiving a .rar archive containing many files with special characters é&€ ....
We need to extract it on a remote server using the shell.

If I use `unrar x archive/name where/to/extract/`, the extraction goes well.
The issue is that every file with a special character is truncated and looses its extension:

```
vidéo.jpeg  => vid
lolèo.pdf => lol
```

I really need to keep the fullname & the extension.
I tried using the rar command it made things even worse.
Any idea how to solve this problem?

The only way we found is to extract the file using a windows operating system and then send the files to the remote server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `unrar` process is running in an Unicode-based locale.

While RAR archives always contain file names stored in Unicode, there's no mandated filename encoding for Linux in general – programs need to look at the current system locale in $LANG and transform the name accordingly.

If no locale was set, then the default is assumed to be ASCII and the re-encoding done by `unrar` fails as soon as it encounters a character that cannot be represented in the system locale. On the other hand, if the locale says UTF-8, then it can represent *any* Unicode character.

1. First check `locale -a` for currently available locales. In some newer distributions (e.g. Debian Bullseye), the locale `C.UTF-8` is always available and you can just go directly to step 3.

   *(The "locale -a" output will show ".utf8" suffixes; that's normal and will also work, but it's still better to use ".UTF-8" in actual configurations.)*
2. If the list contains an UTF-8 capable locale, choose it (the actual language does not matter). If there aren't any, run `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` to add one. (This process is different between various distros, e.g. on Arch you would need to edit "/etc/locale.gen".)
3. Run `localectl set-locale LANG="xx_XX.UTF-8"` to select the locale; this will write to /etc/locale.conf or /etc/default/locale or some similar file.
4. If you're using 'unrar' via SSH – log out, then log back in again (to refresh environment), and run `locale` to make sure the LANG configuration took effect, and `locale charmap`  to make very sure your locale is based on UTF-8.

   If you have a service that runs 'unrar' – either reboot the whole server, or run `sudo systemctl set-environment LANG="xx_XX.UTF-8"` and restart that service.